# How to use enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

The method `enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:` is in class `NSData`, and interpreted in Apple Documentation as following:

> Enumerate through each range of bytes in the data object using a block.
>   `- (void)enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:(void (^)(const void *bytes, NSRange byteRange, BOOL *stop))block`
>
> ### Parameters
>
> `block`
>   The block to apply to byte ranges in the array.
>
> > The block takes three arguments:
> >     `bytes`
> >     The bytes for the current range.
> >     `byteRange`
> >     The range of the current data bytes.
> >     `stop`
> >     A reference to a Boolean value. The block can set the value to YES to stop further processing of the data. The stop argument is an out-only argument. You should only ever set this Boolean to YES within the Block.
>
> ### Discussion
>
> The enumeration block is called once for each contiguous region of memory in the receiver (once total for a contiguous NSData object), until either all bytes have been enumerated, or the stop parameter is set to YES.

But my question is, when will the block be executed? Which method is responsible for providing arguments `bytes`, `byteRange` and `stop` for the block? For example, if I want to traverse a part of the bytes array, what should I do to control?

Answer (score 8):

The `bytes`, `byteRange` and `stop` parameters are passed to your block by `enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock`.  You don't specify which bytes you want to traverse - you use this method to traverse all of the bytes (You can terminate early via `stop`).

As a simple example, say you wanted to search through some `NSData` looking for a 0xff.  You could use -

```
NSInteger ffFound=NSNotFound;
[myData enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:^(const void *bytes, NSRange byteRange, BOOL *stop) {
   for (NSInteger i=0;i<byteRange.length;i++) {
      if (bytes[i]== 0xff) {
         ffFound=byteRange.location+i;
         *stop=YES;
         break;
      }
   }
}];

if (ffFound != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"0xFF was found at location %ld",(long)ffFound);
}
```

Comment: Typo in `for` loop. `byteRange` should be `byteRange.length`. `i` should be `NSInteger`. Also, one other big flaw. `byteRange.location` will not always be 0. Don't assume it will be.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed that.  I am assuming that the *bytes is always going to be 0 based for the current block. - so bytes[0]=myData[byteRange.location].  byteRange.location is taken into consideration when setting `ffFound`

Comment: @rmaddy The documentation is confusing but it says that bytes is the "bytes for the current range". I found another example in Google that suggests I should use byteRange.location, rather than 0 but that doesn't make sense to me - If that were the case it would be "bytes for data", not "bytes for current range".  Opinion?

Comment: Look at the docs. It's "bytes for current range" and "range of the current data bytes". Lets say the data has 100 bytes. It might come in two chunks. The first might be the first 40 bytes. The `bytes` parameter will be those 40 bytes and `byteRange` will be 0,40. The second pass the `bytes` parameter will be the next 60  bytes and the range will be 40,60. In both cases the first byte of the range will be index 0 but `byteRange.location` isn't 0 both times. So your current code should work.

Comment: That was my interpretation - byteRange.location would change, but the byte buffer would always start at offset 0 from the pointer

Comment: I think maybe we need use `*stop=YES` here since `stop` is a pointer?

Answer (score 4):

`[NSData enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:]` is used for reading **contiguous** region of memory of fetched data which means that as the iterator encounters a new chunk, it will execute the block passed to it.

In addition to that, it is **not guaranteed** that the `block` will be called more than once *(in other words, data may not be fragmented)* and the size of `bytes` passed to block will always be same.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://httpbin.org/image/png"]];

[data enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:^(const void *bytes, NSRange byteRange, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"You get the chunk in range: %@", NSStringFromRange(byteRange));
}];
```

Alternatively, you can also enumerate over the data and read fixed size of chunk at each iteration;

```
NSUInteger length = [data length];
NSUInteger chunkSize = 1024;
NSUInteger chunkOffset = 0;

do {
    NSUInteger chunkSize = MIN(length - chunkOffset, chunkSize);

    NSData *chunk = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(chunkOffset, chunkSize)];
    chunkOffset = chunkOffset + chunkSize;

} while (chunkOffset < length);
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are good, but didn't answer this part:

> when will the block be executed?

The block will be executed immediately, one or more times, before `-enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:` returns.

You may be confused because many methods which take a block are asynchronous. They return but retain the block and continue to do some work (or monitor some events or input) in the background and call the block later.

`-enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:` is not like that. It's synchronous. It does all of its work before returning to the caller.